# Using to to convert large XML files to JSON to store in MongoDB

Tags: json, xml, mongodb, parsing, go

For a project of mine I have to deal with XML files over 2GB. I would like to store the data mongoDB. I have decided to give it a try using the Go language. But I have a bit of trouble figuring out the best way to do this in Go.

I've seen a lot of examples with a fixed XML structure, but the data structure I get is dynamic, so using some kind of predefined struct isn't going to work for me.

Now I stumbled upon this package: https://github.com/basgys/goxml2json which looks very promising, but there are a few things I don't get:

- The example given in the readme is using a XML string, but I don't see anything in the code that accepts a file.
- Given the example, I have 2GB xml files, I cannot simply load the whole XML file in memory. This would flud my server.

I think it is good to say, I just have to convert the XML data just once to its JSON form so I can store it in mongoDB.

Does some of you have some ideas on how to parse XML files efficiently to JSON using Go?

Comment: Go for interface for dynamic xml and there is no need to convert the xml to json and store into mongoDB. Better is to read the file into chunks and parse it into interface then store the data inside mongoDB.

Comment: Would you mind explaining this a bit? If I understand you correctly you are saying just try to read the XML in a chunked fashion so I won't have to convert it to JSON and store it in mongoDB? Is this correct? If so, of course that is one way to do it, but I would prefer to store it in MongoDB so parsing it to JSON. This because the querying I have to do on this data.

Answer (score 0):

Go provides a [builtin XML stream parser at `encoding/xml.Decoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Decoder).

A typical usage pattern is to read tokens until you find something of interest and then unmarshal the token into an XML tagged struct, then handle that data accordingly.  This way you're only loading into memory what is required for a single XML token *or* to unmarshal an interesting bit of data.

For example ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.com/p/sNuG2VVe1uv)):

```
d := xml.NewDecoder(xmlStream)
for {
  // Decode the next token from the stream...
  token, err := d.Token()
  if err == io.EOF {
    break
  }
  check(err)

  // Switch behavior based on the token type.
  switch el := token.(type) {
  case xml.StartElement:
    // Handle "person" start elements by unmarshaling from XML...
    if el.Name.Local == "person" {
      var p Person
      err := d.DecodeElement(&p, &el)
      check(err)

      // ...then marshal to JSON...
      jsonbytes, err := json.Marshal(p)
      check(err)

      // ...then take other action (e.g. insert into database).
      fmt.Printf("OK: %s\n", string(jsonbytes))
      // OK: {"Id":"123","Name":"Alice","Age":30}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution requires a fixed structure XML, i.e. Person needs to be defined as a struct and so does not answer the OPs question. I also have this problem and if I get a solution I will endeavor to post it here. Although my solution may be to use Python ;-)